# Find questions or answers with the fastest growing score

Tags: feature-request, upvotes, sorting, popularity

The "votes" tab is useful to order questions/answers with the highest overall number of  up-votes first.

But I am also interested in "hot topics", i.e. those that have received the most number of votes within a particular timeframe (e.g. the last 3 months). This might allow me to see questions/answers that may one day overtake the current leaders. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: You might want to see if [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/) can do that for you. [This might get you started](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243458/votes-in-the-data-dump/243462#243462)

Comment: @rene is it possible to recover [meta-tag:timeline] from SEDE?

Comment: @gnat not sure if you're talking about the [post timeline](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254329/self-answered-questions-have-misordered-timeline/254339#254339). Fullrecovery is No, but you can get close...

Comment: @rene I see, thanks. I was thinking about the post timeline: [like this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/254329/timeline) - `http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/254329/timeline`

Comment: Thanks @rene, looks promising - am working on this now...

Comment: Think I got there - see answer below.

Comment: @gnat but... that query I linked to gathers all data (more or less) that is also in the post time line. If that is not the case then the query is wrong. I assume you don't expect me to create a full-blown html page that has the exact same layout by only using sql statements in SEDE ... ;)  hop into chat if I'm misunderstanding you....

Comment: @rene not of course, I am not asking for html. :) It is just great as all details are there, it means one can really build sensible analysis on it, as good one can have by checking real timeline page

Comment: OK, got you. I created the query and answer on the MSE question because /timeline is unsupported and I felt it was better to have something similar ready in case the team decides to go from unsupported to  a 404 page ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an initial attempt:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/368203/find-questions-or-answers-with-the-most-votes-cast-recently-e-g-last-100-days

Not unexpectedly, [the top StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809) received the most votes. But there are some more interesting results below, e.g. [third in the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30727515) (a recent question but possible future contender for one of the top spots?)

Comment: third question is unlikely a contender. [Question timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30727515/timeline) shows two "flashes in the pan" and then things go dead. First flash suggests that it simply stuck in [meta-tag:hot-questions] for about a week, which explains its (mostly artificial if you ask me) popularity. It likely been reddited or something month after posting, and after that, for over a month, there was no substantial interest

Comment: @gnat Good point - I was just looking at raw numbers, which don't tell the whole story. Comparing with [the top answer's timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11227809/timeline) it doesn't have nearly the same level of interest.

Comment: I did something very similar two years ago. Here's my query: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/109387/vote-magnets-posts-with-the-highest-passive-vote-rate Admittedly, it's probably a lot more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Nice! Great compact format that eeks the most out of the screen width. And there's something about the most voted answer ever that must give you a good feeling when looking at the query results....:-)

Comment: Yeah, I wrote a lot of queries during that time. And I'd be lying if I said they weren't influenced by some of my more heavily upvoted answers.